# Spit graphical query plans as jpegs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan, query-planner

I have SQL Server and I want to get a graphical query plan. Then, I want to save it as a .jpg or .png. Is this possible? What tools are available? I am new and can't seem to find much interest in this kind of work - thanks for any help.

Comment: use the snipping tool! https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13776/windows-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots

Comment: Oh sorry I meant programmatically!!

Comment: Saving query plan as image wasting a lot of information, via mouse hover you get more details of it, why do you need that ? it is better to save it as sqlplan file.

Comment: Its just an experiment. What if I wanted to get a query's plan - similar to PostgreSQL EXPLAIN - and store it as text? (SQL Server)